# Выделение память под поля-ссылки в конструкторе без параметров в Java

Tags: java

Поля класса представлены объектными ссылками. 
Вопрос: Должен конструктор по умолчанию выделять под поля-ссылки память?

Пример:

```
 class A {}

 class B {
    A a;

    B() {
      a = new A ();
    }
 }
```

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос, в данном виде не очень понятно что вы хотите узнать

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, переформулировал

Comment: А про какой конструктор по умолчанию идёт речь? В `A`? Ибо в `B` конструктора по умолчанию нет. А вообще, в целом: если вам нужно, то инициализируйте поле в конструкторе. Не нужно - не инициализируйте. При использовании DI вообще может правильнее быть `B(A a) { this.a = a; }`.

Comment: Если вам нужно инициализировать объект в конструкторе - тогда да. Все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под конструктором по умолчанию? В вашем примере он есть в классе `A`.

Comment: @androschuk, что, вы, подразумеваете зависимость от задачи?

Comment: @iksuy, исправился

Comment: @studentST задачи бывают разные. В одних классах нужно что-то инициализировать в конструкторах, в других - нет. Универсальных решений нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно в java не говорят о выделении/освобождении памяти.

Если вопрос в том, нужно ли инициализировать поля члены перед использованием - да нужно.

```
 class A {int v = 5;}

 class B {
    A a;  // a == null

    B() {
    }
    void foo() {
      System.out.print(a.v); // Может вызывать NullPointerException
    }
    void bar() {
      if (a == null) a = new A();
      System.out.print(a.v); // ok
    }
 }

 ////
 B b = new B();
 b.foo(); // NullPointerException - b.a не инициализирована
 b.bar(); // ok
 b.foo(); // ok, ведь a уже инициализирован
```

На примере метода bar показал, что в конструкторе это делать необязательно.

Хорошим тоном является отсутствие в публичном интерфейсе методов, допускающих неконсистентное(использование неинициализированных переменных) состояние класса.

Comment: @Victor, я же написал "перед использованием". *В первой редакции этого не было, да*

Comment: @vp_arth, т.е. если есть в классе поле-ссылка на другой класс - будь добр выдели память в конструкторе без параметров?

Comment: @studentST нет, в ответе про такое не говорится, и в общем случае это не так. Почему, кстати, вы так выделяете именно конструктор без параметров - тоже непонятно. Идея одинакова для всех конструкторов. Перед использованием `a` должно быть проинициализировано. Где происходит инициализация - зависит от конкретной задачи/реализации.

Comment: @studentST нет. Если есть поле, то его необходимо про инициализировать, и неважно где в конструкторе или перед использованием

Comment: Думаю, первый вызов в trycatch заворачивать не стоит =) Понятно же, не?

Comment: @vp_arth да, думаю, try-catch - это уже перебор)